# SqlAlchemy dataclass behavior and declarative mixins: AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-dataclasses

I have a set of classes that I drafted as pure python dataclasses. Here's a stripped down example that behaves as I would expect:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abc import ABC

@dataclass
class Owner:
    name: str = ""

@dataclass
class OwnedThing(ABC):
    owner: Owner = None

@dataclass
class Thing1(OwnedThing):
    name: str = ""


owner = Owner(name="foo")
thing = Thing1( name="bar", owner=owner)
print(thing.owner.name)
```

Here we have a base class that establishes that a number of derived classes will all have an "owner" object. Assigning the owner is straightforward.

When I tried to add SqlAlchemy for persistence, I would like to keep the general inheritance structure so I don't have to repeat this owner-thing relationship for all of the varieties of owned things. However, when I do, I can no longer assign an owner class instance to the `.owner` attribute:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,field
from abc import ABC
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_mixin, declared_attr, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey

@dataclass
class Owner:
    name: str = ""

@declarative_mixin
@dataclass
class OwnedThing(ABC):
    owner_id: int = field(init=False, default=None)
    owner: Owner = None

    @declared_attr
    def owner_id(cls):
        return Column('owner_id', ForeignKey('owner.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def owner(cls):
        return relationship(Owner)

@dataclass
class Thing1(OwnedThing):
    name: str = ""


owner = Owner(name="foo")
thing = Thing1( name="bar", owner=owner)
print(thing.owner.name)
```

This results in this stack trace:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py:658: SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute owner_id from non-mapped class OwnedThing
  default = getattr(cls, a_name, MISSING)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py:658: SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute owner from non-mapped class OwnedThing
  default = getattr(cls, a_name, MISSING)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py:842: SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute owner_id from non-mapped class OwnedThing
  if isinstance(getattr(cls, f.name, None), Field):
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py:842: SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute owner from non-mapped class OwnedThing
  if isinstance(getattr(cls, f.name, None), Field):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_case_sql.py", line 30, in <module>
    thing = Thing1( name="bar", owner=owner)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Note that when I skip having a base class, things work as I'd expect, without error:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,field
from abc import ABC
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_mixin, declared_attr, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey,Integer

@dataclass
class Owner:
    name: str = ""


@dataclass
class Thing1:
    owner_id: int = Column(Integer)
    owner: Owner = relationship("Owner")
    name: str = ""


owner = Owner(name="foo")
thing = Thing1( name="bar", owner=owner)
print(thing.owner.name)
```

I don't know enough about the internals of SqlAlchemy to understand what I'm doing wrong, and I haven't seen anyone else run into this problem before. Can someone help me keep using data-classes and mixins?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that adding the mapping code around the classes fixes the issue:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,field
from abc import ABC
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_mixin, declared_attr, relationship, registry
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer

mapper_registry = registry()

@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Owner:
    __tablename__ = "owner"
    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    name: str = ""

@declarative_mixin
@dataclass
class OwnedThing(ABC):
    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id: int = field(init=False, default=None)
    owner: Owner = None

    @declared_attr
    def owner_id(cls):
        return Column('owner_id', ForeignKey('owner.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def owner(cls):
        return relationship(Owner)

@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Thing1(OwnedThing):
    __tablename__ = "thing"

    name: str = ""


owner = Owner(name="foo")
thing = Thing1( name="bar", owner=owner)
print(thing.owner.name)
```

There are still some warnings, but the code functions as intended now.